# Redirect screen output to text file

Tags: python

My python script calls an executable (binary compiled from C++) like this:

```
subprocess.call(["./rti", '1', '0.05', fileForRTI])
```

where `rti` executable name, `1`, `0.05` and `fileForRTI` are arguments.

This executable generates output to the console, but I want to output it to the text file as well. What I tried is this (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)):

```
import sys

someFile = 'testFile'
sys.stdout = open(someFile, "w")
print(str(subprocess.call(["./rti", '1', '0.05', fileForRTI])))
```

But for some reason what is written to the file is just '1', while output is much bigger.

I also tried this:

```
p = Popen(['./rti', '1', '0.05', fileForRTI], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate(b"input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")
rc = p.returncode
print(rc)
```

But it's once again shows 1.

EDIT: also Kasra's solution give output 1 instead of what I see normally on the screen.

Not sure if allowed, but a side question, if that `./rti` executable takes long time to generate code, so is it possible to stop terminate and output to file what is already seen on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subprocess.check_output()` :

```
import subprocess
try:
    out_bytes = subprocess.check_output(["./rti", '1', '0.05', fileForRTI])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    out_bytes = e.output # Output generated before error
    code= e.returncode # Return code
```

This runs the specified command and returns its output as a byte string. If you need to
interpret the resulting bytes as text, add a further decoding step. For example:

```
out_text = out_bytes.decode('utf-8')
```

The `check_output()` function is the easiest way to execute an external command and
get its output. However, if you need to perform more advanced communication with a subprocess, such as sending it input, you’ll need to take a difference approach. For that,use the `subprocess.Popen` class directly

Comment: Well I get an error with this: `raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['./rti', '1', '0.05', 'autom1Z.data']' returned non-zero exit status 1`

Comment: That's a feature of `check_output()`. Use one of the other related functions from `subprocess` if you need or want to ignore the exit status.

Comment: @estranged You can use an exception handeling , i edit the answer !

Comment: Gotcha! It works but I once again get '1' as an output. Everytime I simply execute program I get normal output to console, but if I output using your method, or ones in my question, I get 1 instead and I cannot see any normal output.

Comment: @Kasra it's compiled C++ binary, which I can run in linux terminal like this: `./rti 1 0.05 fileName`. It sits in same directory as my .py python program. I need to run it from python script, and so far it works, but only I see output to the screen.

Comment: can you change `stdout =PIPE,stdin =PIPE` with `stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
stdin = subprocess.PIPE` ?

Comment: Actually it works, I just was outputting error code instead of output, just like someone in comment said. Thanks sir. Now on a related note, if the executable takes very long to finish, is it possible to terminate it after let's say 5 seconds?

Comment: @estranged you're welcome you can use `signal` package , read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-python-function-call